# How can I Install Cocos3D for iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, installation, cocos3d

How can I Install Cocos3D for iPhone/iPad?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here goes the solution very explained with screen shots

http://www.techipost.com/2011/02/20/installing-cocos3d-for-iphoneipad/

Answer (score 2):

You can also download and install [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com), which includes Cocos3D and a readymade Cocos3D example project that works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the [official cocos3d site](http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/):

> Once downloaded, unzip the file and
>   **follow the instructions in the README
>   document** to run the install-cocos3d
>   script from an OSX Terminal session.
>   Since cocos3d is built on top of
>   cocos2d, you will also need to
>   download the latest version of cocos2d
>   before running the installation
>   script.