# How to install cocos3d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Cocos3D for iPhone/iPad ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057563/how-to-install-cocos3d-for-iphone-ipad)

I have already install cocos2d template.How to install cocos 3d template?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you head to this link: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/04/cocos2d-installer-updated-added-cocos3d/ there you can download an installer that will install cocos3d and cocos2d + all templates. Just follow the instructions provided. The installer was created by Steffen Itterheimer, he'll be happy if you leave some feedback ;)